# Is it possible to trigger during an SQL table insertion using Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am currently working on azure logic app, my scenario is I want to get the newly created record from azure SQL database and then insert it into Dynamics CRM.

For that I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) link, in that comments section someone mentioned like right now there is no trigger during an SQL table insertion using Logic Apps. I know there is preview version available but I don’t know how to access it.

Can you please tell how to access preview version of it and how to do that with out using trigger during SQL table insertion?

Answer (score 3):

The team has introduced triggers in the sql connectors that enable you to trigger your logic apps when there is a new record found. **You can find the trigger under SQL Server section of available triggers.**

Quoting from the [blog posts](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/)

> The triggers do have the following limitations:
>
> > - It does not work for on-premises SQL Server
> > - Table must have an IDENTITY column for the new row trigger
> > - Table must have a ROWVERSION (a.k.a. TIMESTAMP) column for the modified row trigger
>
> The table must have a column whose value is unique and whose value increases (or decrease) monotonically each time such a change is made. This is satisfied by having an IDENTITY column for tracking creation, and ROWVERSION (a.k.a. TIMESTAMP) column for tracking modification.